# A function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined

Tags: c++, function, auto

I have a DLL project created in visual c++ and a CLR project.
In my DLL project I exported a function with 'auto' type.

staff.h

```
extern "C" STAFFS_API auto GetStaffMap();
```

and if staff.cpp it has a std::map return type.

```
std::map<int, std::string> staffMap;
auto GetStaffMap() 
{
  return staffMap;
}
```

Now in my CLR application, 
I call this function:

```
#include <map>
#include "Staff.h"
std::map<int, std::string> staffMap = Staffs::GetStaffMap();
```

And when I compile the program, it has an error that says:

```
C3779 'Staffs::GetStaffMap': a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined.
```

**UPDATE**

I tried,
staff.h

```
extern "C" STAFFS_API auto GetStaffMap() -> std::map<int, std::string>;
```

staff.cpp

```
extern "C" auto GetStaffMap() -> std::map<int, std::string> {
  return staffMap;
}
```

but still have compile error:

```
Error   C2526   'GetStaffMap': C linkage function cannot return C++ class 'std::map<int,std::string,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>'  AmsCppRest  c:\users\laptop-attendance\source\repos\amscpprest\amscpprest\staff.h

Error   C2556   'std::map<int,std::string,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>> Staffs::GetStaffMap(void)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'void Staffs::GetStaffMap(void)'   AmsCppRest  c:\users\laptop-attendance\source\repos\amscpprest\amscpprest\staff.cpp

Error  C2371 'Staffs::GetStaffMap': redefinition; different basic types
```

Comment: How would the compiler type-check the main file? Keep in mind that compiling it separately from staff.cpp is a valid and reasonable thing to do.

Comment: How is it possible *overloaded function differs only by return type from 'void Staffs::GetStaffMap(void)'*? You declared `void GetStaffMap()` somewhere.

Comment: I have a 'void display_json() functions and staffMap variable was inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

`auto`  does not delay finding out the return type of the function. It just makes the compiler look at the implementation to find out what it is `auto`matically. You will have to manually declare the return type in the header since the code that includes the header has to know what the return type is.

Comment: Do you mean I need to change from 'auto GetStaffMap()' into std::map<int, std::string> GetStaffMap() in my staff.h?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: If do that, I will got another error when compiling my DLL project.

Comment: Yeah, probably that you can't extern "C" a std::map. Now that's an entirely different issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare a returned type so a compiler knows it.

```
// Declaration
extern "C" STAFFS_API auto GetStaffMap() -> std::map<int, std::string>;

// Definition
extern "C" auto GetStaffMap() -> std::map<int, std::string>
{
  return staffMap;
}
```

Comment: Hi, doing this would generate another error: C2371 'Staffs::GetStaffMap': redefinition; different basic types

Comment: What a problem is in doing the same in the definition?

Comment: @noyruto88 - You need to specify `extern "C"` at the point of definition as well. The language linkage must match, and it defaults to `extern "C++"` when you don't specify it explicitly.